# Large .tmp files in user's directory

Tags: windows-8

My mother has a new W8 laptop and we were surprised to see the C: drive reported as full. We looked and found 4 .tmp files each about 4Gb in size, in a sub-dir of c:\users\\application data.

I thought Windows kep its own tmp files in c:\windows so what are these files and why are they there? Are they safe to delete?

Comment: What is the modification date of those files?

Comment: what's the name of the parent folder of tmp files?